# Apache error 324 when try download large files

Tags: apache, configuration, download

I installed xampp on win server 2003.

I change php.ini to :

```
max_execution_time = 9000
max_input_time = 9000
memory_limit = 44000M
post_max_size = 45000M
upload_max_filesize = 3000M
```

But when anyone try download larger than 30MB I  see this error :

```
 Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

this error show in one moment before start download we try to download.

I found same question [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43159/xampp-unable-to-serve-files-larger-than-30mb) but not found answer.

How I can solve this problem.

Comment: are you using `Chrome`?

Comment: yes chrome & FF & IDM .

Comment: look here: [error 324](http://www.slideshare.net/JessicaNokk/how-to-fix-error-324-neterremptyresponse).

Comment: This is client advice I'm sure my problem in server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem the VPS ram was 512 MB , when I inc Ram to 1024MB the problem was solved.